# Laravel Eloquent - Is it inefficient

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm looking at developing a new site with Laravel. I was reading a tutorial on http://vegibit.com/laravel-eloquent-orm-tutorial/, regarding using Eloquent to join tables and retrieve data. In the last example they are essentially trying to do a join but still Eloquent is executing two queries instead of one. Is Eloquent inefficient or is this simply a poor example? It seems that this could have simply been done with a single left join query. Can anyone provide some insight on this? Is there a better way to execute this query? The specific example is:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $paintings = Painting::with('painter')->get();

    foreach($paintings as $painting){
        echo $painting->painter->username;
        echo ' painted the ';
        echo $painting->title;
        echo '<br>';
    }

});
```

Results in the following queries:

```
string ‘select * from paintings‘ (length=25)
string ‘select * from painters where painters.id in (?, ?, ?)’ (length=59)
Leonardo Da Vinci painted the Mona Lisa
Leonardo Da Vinci painted the Last Supper
Vincent Van Gogh painted the The Starry Night
Vincent Van Gogh painted the The Potato Eaters
Rembrandt painted the The Night Watch
Rembrandt painted the The Storm on the Sea of Galilee
```

Comment: I'm no authority on the subject but as I see it, eloquent is always going to be slower than talking directly to the DB because there is overhead in creating the query, and then binding all results to instances of whatever model you're using. It won't be an unbearable amount of overhead by any means but it'll be there in some form. Whats the kind of load you're expecting on your new project?

Comment: You can always create views and have read-only eloquent models for easy database access. My stab at this would be that eloquent won't perform a join because each model is isolated on its own and you can update each one, regardless of any type of relation between them, which might be the reason it chooses to do two queries for easier mapping to objects. Then again, I could be wrong, but the fact is - if you want a join, a single query and all the benefits of eloquent - you can have achieve it.

Comment: I haven't made any final decision as of yet. In previous projects I have always manually written my queries, so I'm not adverse to that. A friend was recently bragging about how easy Eloquent was, but I'm not seeing a real advantage when I can whip up the queries pretty quickly. We're expecting a load with some complex queries, so efficiency will be important.

Comment: You'll be quicker with Eloquent. It's not that queries are difficult to construct, what Eloquent does for you is enabling you to quickly perform crud over a set of tables. I'm talking from experience because guys from the office tried to convince me for weeks that Eloquent and Doctrine beat manual querying. After I gave in, I can vouch that using an ORM definitely helps you develop faster, and the best part is that you can conduct testing much, much easier.

Answer (score 3):

Eloquent is extremely useful for building something quickly and also has query caching that it's really easy to use however it might not be ideal for big projects that need to scale over time, my approach is to use Repository pattern with contracts that way I can still use the power of Eloquent and have a system that will allow me to easily change the implementation if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to get all the data in a single query to use joins, then you must specify it as:

```
Painting::join('Painter as p', 'p.IdPainter', '=', 'Painting.IdPainting')->get()
```

And if you need some conditional then:

```
Painting::join('Painter as p', 'p.IdPainter', '=', 'Painting.IdPainting')->where('cond1', '=', 'value')->get();
```

Personally Eloquent is inefficient, i prefer Doctrine in this regard.

Comment: Any facts backing up your statement about Eloquent being inefficient compared to Doctrine, or should we just take your word for it? I like to trust something I can reproduce and see for myself. Your answer doesn't help in that regard.

Comment: If you find Doctrine efficient and eloquent inefficient, then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I speak personally to my, Eloquent not meet my expectations. This review is from experience, I certainly easily make queries why I do not dispute, however this does not have support for more complex structures in the database, an example composite keys, at least natively.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question: No. It is not inefficient.

Using Eloquent in the way described by Jorge really defeats its purpose as an ORM.

Whilst you can write joins as in the example given, an ORM really isn't designed with that in mind.

The example you've given isn't an [n+1 query](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/n_plus_one/) (where there's an additional query run for each item in the loop - the worst type of query).

Using two queries as reported by your output isn't a huge overhead, and I think you'd be fine to use that in production. Your use of Eloquent's 'with' [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading) is precisely what you should use in this context.

An example of an n+1 query (which you want to avoid) is as follows:

```
foreach (Book::all() as $book)
{
    echo $book->author->name;
}
```

If 20 books are returned by `Book::all()`, then the loop would execute 21 queries in total. 1 to get all of the books, and 1 for each iteration of `$book` to get the author's name.

Using Eloquent with eager loading, combined with caching would be enough to minimise any performance issues.